# iphone SDK :How to add more string after an static URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, nsurl

First...if no one can answer this question it's ok...

because I don't know how to ask this question in the correctly description

my program is get the plist data from URL and show it on the iphone tableview

My colleagues give me two URL to get the plist data

So I have two tableviews(**tableview1,tableview2**)

two URLs(**URL1,URL2**)

My **tableview1** via **URL1** get a **plist1** ,and **tableview1** has 3 contents in first 3 rows

ex.(row0  id1),(row1 id2),(row2 id3)

When I select row0 ,it will jump to **tableview2** and with a title **id1** on the navgation bar

so far is I can do...

but at **tableview2** ,it need a URL like: *www.URL2.php?id=1* =>that means...

I have to **add my tableview title after URL2**

to get the right plist related the id 1

my question is .......**URL2** is static,how to make it like dynamic to get the right URL address ???

well.....first time I thought my colleagues will give me a data like array of array

But it's not...I never try use URL like dynamic...

This is code in the **tableview1** to let me get the plist from URL

```
 NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:appDelegate.URL1//I declare the  URL at appDelegate.m for some reasons...
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
      NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                           returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
      NSString *listFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];   
              self.array = [listFile propertyList];//I parse the data from array to tablecview
```

and this is how I parse the title from **Tableview1** to **Tableview2**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableView2 *tb2 = [[TableView2 alloc]init];
    tb2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    tb2.title = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]description];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tb2 animated:YES];   }
```

Any ideas ?

well ...if someone can answer this or give me a direction I will very appreciate

**Great Thanks for All Reply and Answers !!!**

Oh...one more thing,I can use *ASIHTTPRequest* to post a data

but I don't know how to get data after post ...?(is this help ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a string that you want to append to appDelegate.URL1 declared as:

```
NSString *stringToAppend = @"whatever";
```

Then you can produce a string containing the new URL:

```
NSString *newURLAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[appDelegate.URL1 absoluteString],stringToAppend];
```

And an NSURL from this string:

```
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newURLAsString];
```

And the NSURLRequest from that:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL
                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to say.

You want to load tableView1 from www.foo.com then when the user clicks a row it directs to another URL such as www.foo.com/row0.

The easiest way to acomplish that would be to create a property that you set in your selectedRow method

Something along the lines of.

Declare the property in your header

```
@Property (readwrite,copy) NSString* strURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

**To append the String to api**
**when you want to pass some string to your Api as a parameter**
**For example** I store the lat and long of user and then pass that string to API's url

```
NSURL *address1=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false",location]];

NSLog(@"your lat and long is::%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/90caafb557ba6bf7/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/%@.json",location]);
```

**Here Location is a NSString which store the latitude and longitude and i pass that data to API to fetch City,Country and tempetature etc..**
**with the help of %@ we can pass the stored value to api**